# Advice on using IMvxMessenger vs using a Service based event

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am creating 10-20 core services in a large application that need to publish various events.  I have looked at the IMvxMessenger model and I am trying to ascertain the value in using IMvxMessenger events vs events that are published via our application services.

The main advantage I have with the event being published via one of our services is that developers who use the service can quickly determine what events are available.

e.g. myService.ObserveLogonChange() or myService.LogonChangedEvent etc.

When looking at IMvxMessenger it allows you to publish any class in a very generic way – but knowing how to subscribe to these relies heavily on the developers having a deeper understanding of the code base to know which events to listen too.

So my question is, Is there anything that I lose by having the service publish the event vs the IMvxMessenger approach?

Thanks in advance.

Alan.

Comment: Just came across http://deapsquatter.blogspot.com.au/2013/04/using-mvx-messenger-for-loosely-coupled.html which gives the reasons for the Mvx - Just hoping that there is some compromise that gives you the best of both worlds.  i.e Discoverable event model + no memory issues....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a pattern that might work for you.

**EDIT: Sample code is located here ->** https://github.com/kiliman/MvxEventsSample

Basically, create an inner class in your service class named `Events`. This will have properties for each event that is published by your service. Then in your view model, you create an instance of this Events class and add whatever handlers you want. This way, you have a nice descriptive class showing what events are available, but still uses `MvxMessenger` to ensure weak references.

```cs
public interface IMyService
{
    void Logon();
    void DoSomething();
}

public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly IMvxMessenger _messenger;

    public MyService(IMvxMessenger messenger)
    {
        _messenger = messenger;
    }

    public void Logon()
    {
        _messenger.Publish(new LogonChangedMessage(this));
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        _messenger.Publish(new AnotherEventMessage(this, string.Format("Do Something at {0}", DateTime.Now)));
    }

    // Events class defines all possible events as properties
    // Notice that we only need setters
    // We also store the subscription tokens
    public class Events
    {
        private readonly IMvxMessenger _messenger;

        public Events(IMvxMessenger messenger)
        {
            _messenger = messenger;
        }

        private MvxSubscriptionToken _logonChangedToken;
        public Action<LogonChangedMessage> OnLogonChanged
        {
            set { _logonChangedToken = _messenger.Subscribe(value); } 
        }

        private MvxSubscriptionToken _anotherEventToken;
        public Action<AnotherEventMessage> OnAnotherEvent
        {
            set { _anotherEventToken = _messenger.Subscribe(value); }
        }
    }

    public class LogonChangedMessage : MvxMessage
    {
        public LogonChangedMessage(object sender) : base(sender)
        {
        }
    }

    public class AnotherEventMessage : MvxMessage
    {
        public AnotherEventMessage(object sender, string text) : base(sender)
        {
            Text = text;
        }

        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here's how you would use it in the view model. Notice how I create an instance of `MyService.Events`, and then use lambda expressions to setup the event handlers.

```cs
public class FirstViewModel : MvxViewModel
{
    private readonly IMyService _myService;
    private readonly MyService.Events _events;
    private int _counter = 0;

    public FirstViewModel(IMyService myService, IMvxMessenger messenger)
    {
        _myService = myService;

        // Initialize event handlers using lambda expressions
        _events = new MyService.Events(messenger)
        {
            OnLogonChanged = message =>
            {
                Hello = "OnLogonChanged: " + (++_counter);
                Mvx.Trace("OnLogonChanged");
            },
            OnAnotherEvent = message =>
            {
                Hello = message.Text;
                Mvx.Trace("OnAnotherEvent");
            }
        };
    }

    private string _hello;
    public string Hello
    {
        get { return _hello; }
        set { _hello = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Hello); }
    }


    private MvxCommand _logonCommand;
    public ICommand LogonCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _logonCommand = _logonCommand ?? new MvxCommand(_myService.Logon);
            return _logonCommand;
        }
    }

    private MvxCommand _doSomethingCommand;
    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _doSomethingCommand = _doSomethingCommand ?? new MvxCommand(_myService.DoSomething);
            return _doSomethingCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kiliman for that.  This looks like a strategy that you have used before?  If it is are there any gotchas - because it looks like an elegant approach.

Comment: I haven't used it in the past, but something I've thought about before. Your question prompted me to actually write a sample. You can get the code from github (see link at top of answer).

Comment: Thanks again Kiliman - I really appreciate your effort on this.  I see on JabbR Stuart replied with - "@Kiliman looks neat - interesting approach. The only thing I'd add is that frequently (maybe 40% of the time?) people want to unsubscribe - so frequently they want to add some kind of hook from View to ViewModel about when the View disappears".  Being relatively new to Mvx is there some simple way to bulk unsubscribe to the events of MyService.Events?  Thanks.

Comment: I updated my sample code to support unsubscribing. Basically you derive from the `EventsBase` class which has a method `SetHandler`. This allows you to set the Action property to null and it will take care of unsubscribing.

Comment: Thanks @Kiliman - I gave it a blast and found two issues - one I was able to solve by adding a check for action !=null as illustrated in the code snippet below from the EventsBase.SetHandler method.

`    //Check that action is not null (Can occur if unsubscribe invoked multiple times 
    //without matching subscription)
    if (action != null)
    {
      token = _messenger.Subscribe(action);
    }`

Comment: The other issue - Actually - I am not entirely is an issue, but this relates to the underlying _messenger collection.  After the events are unsubscribed I notice that there are still two _subscription entries (albeit with null values and just the keys) in the underlying non public_messenger._subscriptions._Items collection.  I don't know if this is expected behaviour and maybe it is fine to have these in place?

Again - many thanks.

Alan.

Comment: I can't say that I know how the internals of MvxMessenger work. I do know that subscriptions use a WeakReference so the GC will be able clean them up. Anyway, keep me posted on how it works for you. I'd love to see Pull Requests as you find issues or enhancements.

Comment: Ok Kiliman - I have created a pull request for my change.  I am not sure if I will use this approach because of the persistence of the items in the non public_messenger._subscriptions._Items collection.  I may try to experiment with this a little further if I get sometime.  Thanks.

Comment: I like the general idea, but I don't like this particular implementation. If the service I'm using doesn't live in the core project, I can't access the event class since I can't reference that service's class. It would be better to define the Events class near the service interface, or possibly define an interface for the events so you can use IoC and gain testability.

Comment: @Bognar Thanks for the comments. Yeah, I'm pretty sure this can be improved a lot. It was just a simple example to get the idea across.